# HOW STRONG IS ACETIC ACID?

Tags: acid-base

Will **acetic acid** cause irritation on our skin?
 Does it have any specific smell? what is it's **pH** range? Is it too strong to cause irritation in our nasal passage?

Comment: Your second question is a proof that you've never encountered acetic acid and hence probably should not worry about your remaining questions.

Comment: Ever smell vinegar?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the concentration of acetic acid you use. We have dilute acetic acid in our kitchens (vinegar) so low concentration (Approx 3-9% v/v) is okay. The smell is acidic but is bearable. The pH of vinegar is around 2.4.  On the opposite scale glacial acetic acid (99%), causes severe skin burns and is flammable. It has a very strong acidic smell and will most probably burn your nasal passage or severely irritate it. Hope this helps.